# box2d is out of sync

Tags: java, concurrency, libgdx, box2d

I'm calling `world.step(timeStep, iterations, iterations)` in one thread and in `Screen.render()` which is another thread, this:

```
MyBox2DDebugRenderer.render(world, cam.combined);
```

After some time, I'll get

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2328
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
    at com.kingx.spacejourney.MyBox2DDebugRenderer.renderBodies(MyBox2DDebugRenderer.java:132)
    at com.kingx.spacejourney.MyBox2DDebugRenderer.render(MyBox2DDebugRenderer.java:74)
    at com.kingx.spacejourney.Universe.render(Universe.java:85)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:449)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

**MyBox2DDebugRenderer.java**

```
130    int len = world.getContactList().size();
131    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
132        drawContact(world.getContactList().get(i));
```

So while rendering, box2d world is changing. Do you have some ideas how to synchronize this ? Should I put it in one thread ?

Comment: Have you already tried putting it in one thread?

Comment: I could, that would solve the problem, probably. But two threads will do more work.

Comment: use one thread and fix your timestep: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 0):

As you said, box2d world is changing while rendering and this creates this threading issue.

What you can do is use a Java `synchronized`primitive to be sure that only one thread at a time will be able to access the box2d resources, i.e. :

1st thread (game update):

```
synchronized(world){
   ...
   // Make the physics work by stepping into time
   world.step(1 / 50.0f, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);
   ...
}
```

2nd thread (rendering):

```
synchronized(world){
   ...
   // Your rendering
   MyBox2DDebugRenderer.render(world, cam.combined);
   ...
}
```

Here using `world`is not the only option, you could also use a reference to `this`if both thread coexist in the same class.

Regarding your option of putting everything in a single thread, it would certain solve your problem. However, in my opinion, separating rendering and update in two threads is a great idea. First, you will better use your CPU resources (which probably is able to run several thread in parallel, also in mobile platforms). Second, your game will be easier to scale if the speed of game update and rendering are separated.

Regards,

Comment: I think the problem with this answer, is that the OP wanted to step his box2d world in a thread separate from the libGDX rendering thread. The problem is, if you end up making the render thread wait for anything, libGDX will die in an ugly way.

Comment: Actually you have to make libGDX wait for rendering if you have to... For instance, you can't remove objects from box2d anytime you want. The solution stated above works, at least in my own code (see [here](https://github.com/hevs-isi/gdx2d)).

Comment: Is there a way to make the render thread wait?

I figured out that box2d is multithreading anyway, so calling step in the render thread is probably not a big deal.